# Unexpected change of excel formula coming out of VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below VBA example code that should populate the `SumSQ` range with the same formula as I've defined in the code

> > =SUMSQ(RC13-RC11,RC16-RC14,RC19-RC17,RC22-RC20,RC25-RC23)/(MONTH(TODAY())-MONTH(DATE(2016,1,1)))

```
Sub Prep()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim CBS As Range
    Dim SumSQ As Range

    'Set range from C3 to final row of column C
    Set Sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With Sh
        Set CBS = .Range("C6:C" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Set SumSQ = .Range("AV6:AV" & CBS.End(xlDown).Row)
    End With

    SumSQ.Formula = "=SUMSQ(RC13-RC11,RC16-RC14,RC19-RC17,RC22-RC20,RC25-RC23)/(MONTH(TODAY())-MONTH(DATE(2016,1,1)))"

End Sub
```

However, for some reason in the actual spreadsheet after running the macro, the actual formulate that is getting populated for all cells in the range is:

> > =SUMSQ(R[7]C[423]-R[5]C[423];R[10]C[423]-R[8]C[423];R[13]C[423]-R[11]C[423];R[16]C[423]-R[14]C[423];R[19]C[423]-R[17]C[423])/(MONTH(TODAY())-MONTH(DATE(2016;1;1)))

In case it's of relevance, my locale settings use `;` instead of `,` in formulas

Comment: Just guessing, but can you change SumSQ.Formula to SumSQ.Formular1C1?

Comment: @Vityata is correct.All your intended R1C1 references are also valid A1 addresses, which is why you're getting that result.

Comment: Are they R1C1 addresses? or are you referencing column RC (column 471)

Comment: Haha Thank you! `.formulaR1C1` worked perfectly

Comment: your RC style reference seems doubtful. It is R2C2 OR R[2]C[2] for absolute and relative references. Please see [RC Style Reference](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65565270/stackoverflow/Jun_2016/RC%20STYLE%20REFERENCE.png) for getting my view point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am posting this as an answer as well:
Can you change `SumSQ.Formula` to `SumSQ.Formular1C1`?